# Public Declaration of slider value

Tags: objective-c

I'm currently working on a calculator that uses a custom percentage to calculate the tax.

So i got my layout and the basic functions. The problem only is that when i try to call the 'percentage' value to use in the calculator it gives me 'Local declaration of variable percentage'. Does any one know if there is an easy fix to this?

Thanks!

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    NSUInteger percentage = (int)lroundf(sender.value);
    self.sliderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", percentage];
}

-(void)logic:(int)type{
    if(type == 0){ // Equals
        if(optopt == 1){
            stack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [stack doubleValue]+result];
            btw = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [stack doubleValue]*percentage/100];
            totaal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [stack doubleValue]+[btw doubleValue]];

        }else if(optopt == 2){
            stack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [stack doubleValue]-result];
            btw = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [stack doubleValue]*percentage/100];
            totaal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [stack doubleValue]+[btw doubleValue]];

        }else if(optopt == 3){
            stack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [stack doubleValue]*result];
            btw = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [stack doubleValue]*percentage/100];            totaal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [stack doubleValue]+[btw doubleValue]];

        }else if(optopt == 4){
            stack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [stack doubleValue]/result];
            btw = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [stack doubleValue]*percentage/100];
            totaal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [stack doubleValue]+[btw doubleValue]];

        }

        [_subTotaalLabel setText: stack];
        [_btwLabel setText:btw];
        [_totaalLabel setText:totaal];
        [_opperator setText:@"="];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem is when you are trying to call percentage value,and you have already used percentage variable in  `[stack doubleValue]*percentage/100];`

and you are also use this variable in this code so duplication of name of percentage.. you should change the name in Button Click Method

```
NSUInteger perct = (int)lroundf(sender.value);
self.sliderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", perct];
```

Comment: But if I change the name of the button clicked variable how will it get the value from the slider? Thats the main point; I want to use the slider value in the equation.

Comment: @MartN you change only need to change Variable Name your problem is duplication of same name .. in you IBAction Method u can change ..see my update

Comment: It did fix the local declaration. But now, how do I get my slider value into the void logic(equation)?

Comment: you need to pass the Argument in that Function and call method in Button's Value Change Event

Comment: It worked, thank you! I used your part of the code and added a simple new variable : percentageSave = perct; and used the percentageSave in the equation. Thanks again! :)